# is there any way to get results of grouping along with all the matched regex strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the result of regex matches along with the group matches

input string :

```
  var str= ' application [<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">\n%common;] <!ENTITY % name PUBLIC "public_ID" "URI">'
```

regex :

```
   var rg = /<!ENTITY\s+[\%|\&]?\s*(\S+)\s+(PUBLIC|SYSTEM)\s+"([^"]*)"\s*(?:"([^"]*)"\s*)?>/g
```

applying

```
str.match(rg)
```

only results into string of matches:

```
["<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">", "<!ENTITY % name PUBLIC "public_ID" "URI">"]
```

How to get the results of group matching?

for example in this case i was expecting something like this :

```
[{
   matched : "<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">",
   groups : ["common", "SYSTEM", "../common.ent"]
}, {
   matched : "<!ENTITY % name PUBLIC "public_ID" "URI">",
   groups : ["name", "PUBLIC", "public_ID", "URI"]
}]
```

EDIT :
just little curious to know how regex101.com
showing this [image]

Ref : http://regex101.com/r/oU0qN5/1

Comment: Did my answer help, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in javascript in one call, you have to call this in a loop

```js
var str= ' application [<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">\n%common;] <!ENTITY % name PUBLIC "public_ID" "URI">';
var rg = /<!ENTITY\s+[\%|\&]?\s*(\S+)\s+(PUBLIC|SYSTEM)\s+"([^"]*)"\s*(?:"([^"]*)"\s*)?>/g;

var result;
var results = [];
while(result = rg.exec(str)){
  results.push(result);
}

// this part and they join is just to display the result
document.getElementById("result").innerText = results.join("@@@@");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML.replace("@@@@","<br/>");

// tested with Win7 Chrome 38+
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

not in the structure that you wanted, but like this it can be done in Javascript